# iOS Execute method after ConnectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uipickerview

I currently have the problem that my `UIPickerView numberOfComponents` gets called before my Array gets populated in ConnectionDidFinishLaunching. Which results in 0 rows.

2 Properties at top of view:

```
@property NSArray *JSONArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableData *data; //De Data
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *expositionPicker; //picker
```

Viewdidload:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dtprojecten.ehb.be/~IPBOZAR3C/API/GetAllExpositions.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

FinishLaunchOptions (also some methods like didReceive data were correctly implemented)

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection{
NSLog(@"DidFinishLoading");
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",(unsigned long)[self.data length]);
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

self.JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", self.JSONArray);

NSLog(@"JSONARRAY: %lu",(unsigned long)self.JSONArray.count); //CHECK
NSLog(@"objectAtIndex 0 = %@", [[self.JSONArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]); //CORRECT
NSLog(@"objectAtIndex 1 = %@", [[self.JSONArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"name"]); //CORRECT

//[self.expositionPicker reloadInputViews];

[self.expositionPicker reloadAllComponents]; //NOT WORKING ?}


- (long)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1; }


- (long)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (self.JSONArray != NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Aantal rijen moeten voorzien worden:%lu", [self.JSONArray count]); //WRONG

    return [self.JSONArray count];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Deze array is leeg!");
    return 0;
} }

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [[self.JSONArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"name"]; }
```

Anyone can help me out on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Done, added codeblocks

Comment: Didn't you post this question earlier? What happened to that other question?

Comment: Have you verified that `self.expositionPicker` is not `nil`?

Comment: What do I have to do if "null"? insantiate it ? and what then? Altough i created a UIPicker in my .h file

Comment: How are you creating the picker? Through code or Interface Builder? If in code you need to create the picker view in your `viewDidLoad` method. If through Interface Builder, make sure you connect the outlet.

Comment: The picker was dragged in the IB and then ctrl+drag to create outlet